# Porting C# WinForms app to Linux/OS X using Mono in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform

I don't quite understand how I can port my .NET app to Linux/OS X using Mono. Some tutorials say that I should set Mono target framework in my Visual Studio,
but some others say that I should port my .NET app using MoMA. So for me it's really hard to understand what I need and what's the best way to do this, so can you explain me how I can port my .NET(C# WinForms) app to Linux/OS X using Mono in Visual Studio?